# Numerically solve differential equation with limits of integration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I am trying to solve the following equation, $c$ is a constant and $f(0)$ is known. I've never solved a differential equation that used the limits of integration and I'm unsure how to proceed. It seems to me that the easiest way to solve it would be numerically, but how do I do that? I have the Python SciPy library configured, is there a function I can use in there?

$f(t)=c(f(0)-\int_0^t f(s)ds)$

Thanks!

Comment: Differentiate both sides with respect to $t$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiate both sides w.r.t. $t$
$$f(t)=c\left(f(0)-\int_0^t f(s)ds\right)$$
$$f(t)=c f(0)-c \int_0^t f(s)ds$$
$$f'(t)=-c f(t)$$
$$f(t)=\alpha \exp(-c t)$$
$$\alpha \exp(-c t)=c\alpha-c \alpha \frac{1-\exp(-c t)}{c}$$
$$\alpha \exp(-c t)=c\alpha-\alpha +\alpha \exp(-c t)$$
Thus $c\alpha=\alpha$, which only holds if $c=1$ or $\alpha=0$. Thus, the only differentiable nontrivial solution is $$f(t)\propto \exp(-t)$$ which only exists if $c=1$.